# Como passar uma variável do controller para o service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma dúvida, como eu passo para um service uma variável do controller?

Tenho uma tela que tem uma tabela, quando o usuário clicar em uma linha dessa tabela, ele vai para outra tela com os dados preenchidos em inputs. Dei uma pesquisada na internet, e vi algumas pessoas sugerindo para gravar essa variável em um service, para poder chamar em outro controller, porém não consegui fazer funcionar:

Usuário clica na linha selecionada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ao clicar, a tela muda, e os dados (Tipo ativo e vencimento) selecionados devem aparecer nos seguintes inputs:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código do que eu estava tentando fazer:

**Página da tabela (tabela de teste):**

template:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>

                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Tipo Ativo
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Emissor
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Código
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Emissão
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Vencimento
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-click="$ctrl.teste()">
                            <td>
                                1
                            </td>
                            <td id="teste">
                                TB - Monthly
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Default
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Default
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                01/04/2012
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                01/04/2012
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```

Controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

class PesquisaAtivosController {
  constructor($state, $scope, testeService){
    this.$state = $state;
    this.testeService = testeService;
  }

  teste(){
    var ItemSelecionado = document.getElementById('teste');
    console.log(teste);
    var _this = this;
    _this.$state.go("home.boletoEstoque2");
  }
}

PesquisaAtivosController.$$ngIsClass = true;
PesquisaAtivosController.$inject = ['$state','testeService'];

angular.module('app')
  .controller('PesquisaAtivosController', PesquisaAtivosController);})();
```

**Página que deverá receber os dados:**

Template: apenas criei um botão com a função de aparecer essa variável no console

controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

class BoletoEstoqueController {
constructor($state, $scope, testeService) {
  this.$state = $state;
  this.$scope = $scope;
  this.testeService = testeService;
}

teste(){
  testeService.getItem();
  console.log(ItemSelecionado );
}

}

BoletoEstoqueController.$$ngIsClass = true;
BoletoEstoqueController.$inject = ['$state', 'testeService'];

angular.module('app')
  .controller('BoletoEstoqueController', BoletoEstoqueController);
})();
```

**Service:**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

function testeService($http, $q) {

    var ItemSelecionado = document.getElementById('teste');

    return {
        getItem: function () {
            return ItemSelecionado;
        },
        setItem: function(value) {
            ItemSelecionado = value;
        }
    };

}

testeService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

angular.module('app')
    .service('testeService', testeService)
})();
```

Comment: não entendi bem, se você for usar uma service na controller, não pode passar por parâmetro quando executar alguma function da service?

Comment: Eu quero gravar uma variável no service, para chamar esse service em outro controller e utilizar essa variável

Comment: vou colocar alguns prints na pergunta

Comment: Caso seja código, coloque-o ao invés de print!

Comment: Ok, coloquei alguns prints e códigos de onde eu parei

Comment: @guilhermedjc essa tabela, você tem esses dados em um objeto javascript? pois se tiver, você pode passar esse objeto como parâmetro no service. Assim qualquer controller que acessar o service, estará acessando o mesmo dado que está sendo exibido na sua tabela.

Comment: Não, ainda não, essa tabela eu fiz para teste mesmo colocando os dados diretamente no template.

Comment: Crie uma variável no topo da sua service, depois crie uma function que leia/grave valor nessa variável. Na primeira controller chame essa function passando o valor que deseja e na outra chame a function que devolve o valor, veja esse exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181543/4730201
outra solução é usar `broadcast`

Comment: Você está usando ui-router ou algo do tipo?

Comment: @guilhermedjc primeiro passo é você colocar estes dados em um objeto, crie este objeto de mude seu exemplo usando ele, assim posso te ajudar a criar o service e o controller de forma adequada.

Comment: Beleza Rodrigo. Sim Marcus, estou usando ui-router

Comment: @guilhermedjc uma dica, quando for fazer um comentário direcionado a aoguem coloque o nosso apelido após o @, igual fiz com o seu. Assim eu recebo uma notificação de que houve uma mensagem para mim.